# Regex to find all URL and titles

Tags: php, regex, url

I would like to extract all the urls and titles from a paragraph of text.

```
Les <a href="http://test.com/blop" class="c_link-blue">résultats du sondage</a> sur les remakes et suites souhaités sont <a href="http://test.com" class="c_link-blue">dans le blog</a>.
```

I am able to get all the href thanks to the following regex, but I don't know how to get in addition, the title between the `<a></a>` tags ?

```
preg_match_all('/<a.*href="?([^" ]*)" /iU', $v['message'], $urls);
```

The best would be to get an associative array like that

```
[0] => Array
(
   [title] => XXX
   [link] => http://test.com/blop
)
[1] => Array
(
   [title] => XXX
   [link] => http://test.com
)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: For the umptillionth time on this site, don't use regex to parse/handle HTML. Use DOM instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878604/regex-to-find-all-url-and-titles)

Comment: @EmmanuelN: Why'd you post a link to this page?

Comment: @Rocket I meant [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449618/how-to-find-a-url-from-a-content-by-php)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'm going to study the DOM parser ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still insist on using regex to solve this problem you might be able to parse some with this regex:

```
<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)</a>
```

Note that it doesn't use the U modifier as your did.

**Update:** To have it accept single qoutes, as well as double quotes, you can use the following pattern instead:

```
<a.*?href=(?:"(.*?)"|'(.*?)').*?>(.*?)</a>
```

Comment: `preg_match_all('#<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)</a>#i', $v['message'], $matches);`

Comment: This will fail when double quotes of href container will be single quotes

Comment: @MohanSinfh updated it with support for both. Though I still suggest that you should use a real DOM parser instead of regex

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned in the comments don't use a regular expression but a DOM parser.
E.g.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtml( getExampleData() );

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach( $xpath->query('/html/body/p[@id="abc"]//a') as $node ) {
    echo $node->getAttribute('href'), ' - ' , $node->textContent, "\n";
}

function getExampleData() {
    return '<html><head><title>...</title></head><body>
    <p>
        not <a href="wrong">this one</a> but ....
    </p>
    <p id="abc">
        Les <a href="http://test.com/blop" class="c_link-blue">résultats du sondage</a> sur les remakes et suites souhaités sont <a href="http://test.com" class="c_link-blue">dans le blog</a>.
    </p>
    </body></html>';
}
```

see http://docs.php.net/DOMDocument and http://docs.php.net/DOMXPath

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use RegEx for this.  You should use an XML/DOM parser.  I made this quickly using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

```
$links = array();
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML('Les <a href="http://test.com/blop" class="c_link-blue">résultats du sondage</a> sur les remakes et suites souhaités sont <a href="http://test.com" class="c_link-blue">dans le blog</a>.');
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$a = $xPath->query('//a');
for($i=0; $i<$a->length; $i++){
    $e = $a->item($i);
    $links[] = array(
        'title' => $e->nodeValue,
        'link' => $e->getAttribute('href')
    );
}
print_r($links);
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/2LEn2CAJ

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all("/<a[^>]*href=\"([^\"]*)[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>/", $v['message'], $urls, PREG_SET_ORDER)
```

should work to give you what you want. It's not an associated array, but it should be a nested array in the format you desire.

Answer (score 0):

For people suggesting to use DOM, it might be nice to use DOM. But of course you will not use a FULL DOM parser just to parse couple of urls/titles!

Just use thus regex:

```
/<a.*href="([^" ]*)".*>(.*)<\/a>/iU
```

Comment: Of course I will use a *full* DOM parser to parse a couple of urls/titles.  That's what a DOM parser is for, parsing DOM.